# How can I hide my git token via variable, used in .npmrc file in angular project?

Tags: angular, typescript, git, gitlab, .npmrc

I am creating a package registry in gitlab, for that  git provided me a gittoken that I am using in my .npmrc file . When I am using it directly I am able to publish my registry , when I am accessing it through a variable it is not working as expected.

.npmrc

```
@vproject:registry=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/


'//gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken'="${GITLAB_AUTH_TOKEN}"

'//gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/10058822/packages/npm/:_authToken'="${GITLAB_AUTH_TOKEN}"
```

I have tried to access it using .env file

```
echo "export GIT_AUTH_TOKEN='ABCDEFGHEIBDJd'"
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `${process.env.GITLAB_AUTH_TOKEN}` ?

Comment: tried with that too, not able to authorize token with this approach